# What algorithms I need for ascii print graph in C++?

Tags: graph, plot, ascii

I have homework ASCII drawer for Bar plot, line plot, pie chart and histogram graph from data file. I can't find algorithms ( Exists these algorithms somewhere?

Comment: You will have hell of a time drawing pie chart with ASCII chars, if you can't even figure out, how to draw bar plot... What language do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to generate black and white picture in some plotting library, then go through it in nested cycle and print out " " for white dots and "*" for black ones.